# How to eliminate the animation of the annotation on swift

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit, mkannotationview

I'm using MapKit and I have some annotations on map. They are markerAnnotationViews. The thing is that I want that, when the user touches an annotation, to present  a view controller (without going through a callout accessory view).

For now, I've done so with the `didSelectView with: MKAnnotationView`. But my problem is that when I press the annotation, it expands and shows the following view controller.

Is there a way for the annotation to not expand when the user presses it?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
This is how I present the modal view controller when I press on an annotation:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    
    if let annotation = view.annotation as? FirstAnnotation {
        let rootVC = DetailPinVC()
        rootVC.title = "Detail Pin"
        rootVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .close, target: self, action: #selector(dismissDetailVC))
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
        present(navVC, animated: true)
    } else if let annotation = view.annotation as? SecondAnnotation {
        let rootVC = DetailPinVC()
        rootVC.title = "Detail Pin"
        rootVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .close, target: self, action: #selector(dismissDetailVC))
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
```

And this is my problem. When I dismiss the modal view, the annotation stays expanded on the map. The first photo is before i press on the annotation and the second is after. I want the "bobble" to stay as the first photo:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you past code for how are you presenting the view controller?

Comment: Of course. I updated the question

Comment: Try calling `mapView.deselectAnnotation(<#T##annotation: MKAnnotation?##MKAnnotation?#>, animated: <#T##Bool#>)` in your `didSelect` method. Outside of the if/else statement so it always gets called.

Comment: I thought I already tried that, but I just tried it now and it worked, so thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

The annotation is now selected so it appears different.

To continue using `didSelect` to monitor for tap events on the annotation, call `mapView.deselectAnnotation` immediately within `didSelect`. This will unselect the annotation and return it to the normal unselected size.

Alternatively, you could add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to custom `annotationViews`. This will free up your `didSelect` method so you can readily harness its full use should your app's feature set require it.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    //super.setSelected(false, animated: false)
}
```

in your `MKMarkerAnnotationView` subclass to prevent a selection.